# Emacs, switch to previous window

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, <kbd>C-x o</kbd> takes me to the next window.

What keyboard macro takes me to the previous window in Emacs?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

That'd be <kbd>C-- C-x o</kbd>

In other words, <kbd>C-x o</kbd> with an argument of -1. You can specify how many windows to move by inserting a numeric argument between <kbd>C-u</kbd> and the command, as in <kbd>C-u 2 C-x o</kbd>. (<kbd>C--</kbd> is a shortcut for <kbd>C-u - 1</kbd>)

Comment: And you can use `C-x z` to repeat the last command to quickly switch the windows.

Answer (score 110):

You might also want to try using windmove which lets you navigate to the window of your choice based on geometry. I have the following in my .emacs file to change windows using C-x arrow-key.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <down>") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <left>") 'windmove-left)
```

Comment: coool~~ you have my vote. I am new to emacs (but love it... genius). BTW, what is the 'kbd' standing for??

Comment: BTW, that's similar to [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/)'s commands for [moving to other "frames"](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/doc/Default-Key-Bindings.html#Default%20Key%20Bindings): `C-t Up`, `C-t Down`, etc.

Comment: Note that calling `(windmove-default-keybindings)` binds these functions to SHIFT+up/down/left/right, which I think is more convenient than your `C-x` bindings (which conflict with the also-useful default bindings for `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer`. lkahtz: the `(kbd)` function lets you specify keys in string notation in the more-readable syntax which is also used by Emacs when you use `C-h k` or `C-h c` to describe a binding.

Comment: I don't approve of using arrow keys. But I upvoted for the helpfulness anyway. :smug:

Comment: Can't find windmove on MELPA, but window-jump works the same way. http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/window-jump

Comment: @phils SHIFT + <keys> meddles with shift selection that is enabled by default from Emacs 23 (shift-selection-mode).

Comment: legends2k: True; although you can also pass an argument to `windmove-default-keybindings` to specify a different modifier to use in conjunction with the arrow keys; so that function can still be handy for people who use shift-selection-mode.

Comment: @phils Agreed, _meta_ seems to be a good alternative; [as seen in Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove).

Comment: If you use windmove [I do], I highly suggest using framemove too.

Answer (score 32):

Personally I prefer to use [`window-number.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-es/NumberedWindows)

To select a different window, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> *n*

Where *n* is the number of the window, the modeline of each window shows it's number, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Just download [window-number.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/window-number.el), place it in your emacs load-path and use the following in your `.emacs`

```
 (autoload 'window-number-mode "window-number"
   "A global minor mode that enables selection of windows according to
 numbers with the C-x C-j prefix.  Another mode,
 `window-number-meta-mode' enables the use of the M- prefix."
   t)
```

There's another similar mode called [`switch-window.el`](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window) which gives you big numbers in the windows... (pressing the number switches the window and reverts the display.)

[image]
<sub>(source: [tapoueh.org](http://tapoueh.org/images/emacs-switch-window.png))</sub>

Comment: Nice, but I'd suggest not binding something to `C-x C-j`, as that's the default binding for `dired-jump` if you `(require 'dired-x)`. (See `M-x customize-group RET dired-keys RET` if you want to override that.)

Comment: After posting this I decided to give `switch-window.el` a go, it uses `C-x o` instead, and when there's only two windows active, it just selects the other window.  I think it's wisest to rebind `C-x o` to do  the `window-number` trick, you're quite right about `dired-jump`. Personally I do less window switching and use `C-x b` myself, but having the enhanced `C-x o` is quite pleasing.

Comment: wow amazing Emacs theme in first screenshot. how can I get it?

Comment: @semente on my Emacs related page http://jasonm23.github.com/EmacsFodder/Emacs/2012/06/29/two-new-emacs24-themes/

Comment: @Slomojo the url to your emacs related page ends up in a 404. I'm two years later, I know, but do you have any other page to look at? thanks.

Comment: http://jasonm23.github.io or http://emacsfodder.github.io should have what you are looking for.  Please note the mode line formatter shown (main-line) isn't maintained, (no power-line version is, that I know of.)

Comment: @petrux http://emacsfodder.github.io/blog/two-new-emacs24-themes/ I think this is probably one of the two themes. -  btw.  For a cool mode line try https://gist.github.com/jasonm23/8554119

Answer (score 14):

If you work with multiple emacs windows (>3) a lot and you will want to save some keystrokes add this to your init file and you'll be better off:

```
(defun frame-bck()
  (interactive)
  (other-window-or-frame -1)
)
(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "M-o") 'other-window-or-frame)
(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "M-O") 'frame-bck)
```

Now just cycle quickly thru the windows with M-o

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. All I wanted was for the window switching command to be a single repeating keystroke. Thanks!

I did have to change other-window-or-frame to other-window to make it work, FYI. I'm on Emacs 24.2.1.

Comment: I think these are very good bindings (especially when you have 2+ windows), thanks. As said also hat to change to `other-window` to make it work.

Answer (score 13):

There are some very good and complete answers here, but to answer the question in a minimalist fashion:

```
 (defun prev-window ()
   (interactive)
   (other-window -1))

 (define-key global-map (kbd "C-x p") 'prev-window)
```

Comment: I don't know since when, but emacs has now ``previous-window`` built in.

Comment: @Arne It's not a callable function with `M-x` so should serve a different purpose.

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x p") 'previous-window-any-frame)` work tho

Answer (score 4):

Base on idea from @Nate but slightly modified to support backwards cycling between windows

```
;; Windows Cycling
(defun windmove-up-cycle()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (windmove-up)
    (error (condition-case nil (windmove-down)
         (error (condition-case nil (windmove-right) (error (condition-case nil (windmove-left) (error (windmove-up))))))))))

(defun windmove-down-cycle()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (windmove-down)
    (error (condition-case nil (windmove-up)
         (error (condition-case nil (windmove-left) (error (condition-case nil (windmove-right) (error (windmove-down))))))))))

(defun windmove-right-cycle()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (windmove-right)
    (error (condition-case nil (windmove-left)
         (error (condition-case nil (windmove-up) (error (condition-case nil (windmove-down) (error (windmove-right))))))))))

(defun windmove-left-cycle()
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (windmove-left)
    (error (condition-case nil (windmove-right)
         (error (condition-case nil (windmove-down) (error (condition-case nil (windmove-up) (error (windmove-left))))))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <up>") 'windmove-up-cycle)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <down>") 'windmove-down-cycle)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <right>") 'windmove-right-cycle)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <left>") 'windmove-left-cycle)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @Nate, @aspirin and @Troydm's answer I find this to be a very helpful addition if you decide to bind the windmove commands to whatever key combination you choose:

```
(setq windmove-wrap-around t)
```

With the default configuration you will get an error when you get to attempt to move to a window that doesn't exist which becomes kind of annoying after a while. However when windmove-wrap-around is set then attempting to move off the bottom of the frame for example will instead select the topmost window in the frame. This may be a more intuitive behaviour for you.

Answer (score 4):

`M-n` and `M-p` makes the most sense to me, since they are analogous to `C-n` (**next-line**) and `C-p` (**previous-line**):

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-p") 'previous-multiframe-window)
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-n") 'other-window)
```

(inspired by to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17984479) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305758))

Comment: I've upvoted and used this config. The problem is that `M-n` and `M-p` are already used in terminals (gdb, python, ielm, etc.) so you'll have to switch back to another method to jump out of the terminal buffer.

Comment: What are they used for in those environments?

Comment: That is the best one I seen for the moment, it does not goes against other stuff and works like charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In reference to Nate's answer, I replaced the `arrow keys` to use the traditional `p` for going `up`, `n` for going `down`, `f` for going `right` and `b` for going `left`. I also replaced the `Ctrl` with `Super` key as `C-p, C-n, C-f and C-b` are the default movement keys. This combination with `M` lets you jump characters and lines instead of going through just one by one after each keystroke. Thus `Super` key felt the best choice to keep it an easy key binding. Also, now you don't have to take your hand off the home row any more!

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-p") `windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-n") `windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-f") `windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-b") `windmove-left)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-j"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-k"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window -1)))
```

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> will cycle through your visibles buffers. Forwards and backwards, to be exact.

Comment: M-k is kinda useful shortcut. any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a package that lets you switch windows by using M-. [check this website](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/easy-switching-between-visible-buffers.html). Add this to your init file:

```
(require 'windmove)
(windmove-default-keybindings 'meta) ;; or use 'super to use windows key instead alt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x a") 'ace-swap-window)  
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x q") 'ace-select-window)

download ace-window from the melpa repo if you don't know how to do that
put this in your .emacs file if you don't have one create it 

(package-initialize)                                                                                                                                                                     

(require 'package)                                                                                                                                                                       
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" , "http://melpa.org/packages/"))                                                                                                                

(package-initialize) 

then "m-x list-packages"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method I have found for switching to the previous window is to **mash a couple keys together** as a ["key-chord"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord). The following lets you use your left pinky+ring fingers together to go to previous window:

```lisp
(key-chord-define-global "qw" 'prev-window)
(key-chord-define-global "'y" 'other-window) ; bonus for my colemak, adjust otherwise
(key-chord-define-global ";'" 'other-window) ; probably normal
```

*(This is possible because Emacs key chords are order independent, meaning that `qw` is the same as `wq`.)*