# In Emacs, what is the opposite function of other-window (C-x o)?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs, switch to previous window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91071/emacs-switch-to-previous-window)

`other-window` advances me to the next window in the current frame, but I also want a way to move back to the previous window.

Emacs has `next-buffer` and `previous-buffer`, but no analogous interactive functions for window navigation.  Just `other-window`.

Comment: NOTE: `frame` and `window` are different beasts in Emacs terminology. Please, replace `frame` by `window` in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: frame/window confusion fixed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Provide a negative argument with <kbd>C-u -</kbd> ("Control+U" then "minus"), or even more simply <kbd>C--</kbd> ("Control minus").

- Move to previous window: <kbd>C-- C-x o</kbd>
- Move to previous frame: <kbd>C-- C-x 5 o</kbd>

From code, `(other-window -1)` or `(other-frame -1)` will do the same thing.

Check out the help for the key you want to reverse (e.g. <kbd>C-h k C-x o</kbd> to show help for <kbd>C-x o</kbd>) and if it says "A negative argument..." you know you can use <kbd>C--</kbd>.

Comment: A bit strange but when I have a layout 2x3 windows with windows 1-6 using `C-x o` moves from 3 to 4, but in 4 using `C-u - C-x o` moves from 4 to 2. What would move me from 4 to 3 ?

Answer (score 18):

This is an old post, but I just wondered the same. It seems there now is a function for this in Emacs: `previous-multiframe-window`.

I have it bound to `C-x O`, as in uppercase letter o. Now I just throw in shift when I want to go backwards.

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-x O") 'previous-multiframe-window)`

Comment: One issue with this is that if you have multiple frames this will cycle between them all, when you might want to stay within the current frame only.

Answer (score 10):

Put this in your .emacs, and bind it to whatever key you like

```
(defun back-window ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))
```

Comment: byte-code: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive) (other-window -1)), 3

Comment: @lawlist I got the same error trying to do the same thing as above, only I named my function "previous-window".  The solution was to change the name of the function, because it seemed to conflict with some internal emacs define. Might help your case too.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266109/emacs-defining-function-calling-other-window-with-an-argument-doesnt-work/33266299#33266299

Comment: @Colin -- There is already a built-in function named `previous-window`, so you do **not** want to create your own using the same name -- pick a different name instead.  I am not able to remember the circumstances surrounding my attempted usage of this answer, but I see from the date (May 5, 2013) that I was probably fairly new to Emacs and was just learning how to navigate windows.  Based on my current level of Emacs abilities, I see nothing wrong with the code -- there is no built-in function named `back-window` in the latest developmental master/trunk that would cause a conflict, etc.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly less annoying shortcut available by default is`C-- C-x o`. That way you don't have to switch between Meta and Control while typing the prefixes.

Answer (score 5):

Different from what you asked for, but [the windmove package](http://hovav.net/elisp/windmove-0.93.el) lets you move between windows according to their relative screen locations, which can be much easier than repeatedly doing C-x o.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `C-u -`, you can also give a negative prefix argument with just `M--` (Meta-Minus) , i.e. switch to previous window with `M-- C-x o`.