# Emacs Defining Function Calling other-window with an Argument Doesn't Work

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I would like to define a lisp function to call other-window with an argument of -1 in order to switch to the previous window in the same frame. According to my best research, it should be possible to do this as follows in my emacs file:

```
(defun previous-window ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))
```

However, when I run the function:

```
M-x previous-window
```

I get this:

```
Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive) (other-window -1)), 3
```

Also, weirdly, now when I do this:

```
C-u - C-x o
```

I get:

```
Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive) (other-window -1)), 3
```

If I remove the above function definition from my emacs file, and do this:

```
C-u - C-x o
```

the behavior is as expected.

There does not seem to be a previous definition of previous-window in emacs.

Scratching my head here.

Comment: I changed the name of my custom function name to previous-wind, and now everything works as expected. Seems like defining previous-window conflicts with some already defined function in emacs that is however not visible to the user. Is that possible? Would still like to know the explanation.

Comment: The function `previous-window` is defined in [`window.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/window.c?h=emacs-24#n2630-2667) in the emacs sources.

Comment: well there's the explanation, thanks. Takeaway for discoverers of this question: there are functions defined in emacs that do not tab complete at the minibuffer (M-x) or show up in the docs (C-h a), that you cannot redefine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `C-u - C x o` (where `C x o` is the normal key binding for `other-window`, but your longer `M-x other-window` approach works as well), as `-` by itself indicates a numeric prefix argument of -1.

Comment: This causes the same error, BUT.. it turns out something in my .emacs file is causing all these things to throw an error.  Editing question..