# How can I make window movement commands ignore a certain window?

Tags: emacs, window-management

So I generally have 3 buffers open in Emacs.

1. One buffer for the actual code I am writing.
2. One buffer for the unit test for said code.
3. A third buffer that displays the results of the unit test. This buffer comes into being
   below the two other buffers when I run my unit test <kbd>C-x SPACE</kbd>.

How do I disable this third buffer such that when I press <kbd>C-x o</kbd> I am only switching between buffer 1 and buffer 2? Currently, I switch between buffer 1, then buffer 2, then buffer 3, then buffer 1, etc. To be specific, I want <kbd>C-x o</kbd> to only switch between buffer 1 and 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91071/emacs-switch-active-window

Comment: It sounds like you're asking to skip a *window* when it contains a particular buffer you don't want to switch into.  Correct?

Comment: Stephen, may I suggest you update the title and question to put window instead of buffer ? buffer/window/frame have a specific meaning in emacs: Frame is the equivalent of what a windows manager calls a window (the enclosure you can generally move around). window is what you're referring to: a subset of the frame that shows some text. a buffer is what represents the actual content shown. It's generally identified by a name, that shows in the modeline. You can show the same buffer on 2 windows, e.g.

Comment: window-number-mode is good for this.

Comment: Using smarter movement commands is also a good strategy; see http://github.com/jrockway/elisp/blob/master/_local/term-extras.el for example.

Comment: Ok, I will switch it to buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general solution to this (can look) something like the following:

```
(defvar ignore-windows-containing-buffers-matching-res '("\\*Help")
      "List of regular expressions specifying windows to skip (if window contains buffer that matches, skip)")

(defadvice other-window (before other-window-ignore-windows-containing activate)
  "skip over windows containing buffers which match regular expressions in 'ignore-windows-containing-buffers-matching-res"
  (if (and (= 1 (ad-get-arg 0)) (interactive-p))
      (let* ((win (next-window))
             (bname (buffer-name (window-buffer win))))
        (when (some 'identity (mapcar '(lambda (re)
                                        (string-match re bname))
                                     ignore-windows-containing-buffers-matching-res))
          (ad-set-arg 0 2)))))
```

Customize the variable to be a regular expression matching the buffer names you want to skip.

Comment: I copied this into my .emacs file. I then just replaced "*Help" with "*Ruby-Test*" (which was the name of the buffer that the ruby test were being run within). Now when I switch buffers, it only switches between buffer 1 and 2. Seems like a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Trey's answer will do exactly what you want (at least it looks like it will; I haven't tried it).  A more generic solution would be to use `swbuff` with either `swbuff-x` or my own `swbuff-advice`.  Info about all three can be found on the [Emacs Wiki swbuff page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwBuff).