# How can I prevent emacs switching to some windows with C-x o?

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs-ecb

Is there any way to set some windows non visitable in emacs?

For example, in gdb show-many-windows view, I dont want to switch to local variables window or stack window every time.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574922/how-can-i-make-window-movement-commands-ignore-a-certain-window

Comment: @Patrick Oh, this is pretty. A lot less intrusive than the way I'm going. I should move my answer there.

Comment: I use windmove (S-up, S-down, S-left, S-right) instead of using `C-x o`. Much more likely to get me what I want. http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for letting me know. I was searching for that question for days. And as far as I understand sadly there is no very straightforward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-x o</kbd> is set to `other-window`. It is notoriously hard to customize, but here you go: It respects the [window parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Parameters.html) `'no-other-window`. Your goal will be to do `(set-window-parameter gdb-window 'no-other-window t)`. Now, the only part that remains is to hook us into `gud` and set those properties on the windows.

A good start is

```
(defun make-selected-window-unselectable ()
  (interactive)
  (set-window-parameter (selected-window) 'no-other-window t))
(global-set-key "\M-p" 'make-selected-window-unselectable)
```

Someone will probably haggle about the name, as the window is not truly unselectable, but it will make do.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like it will work for me. But I am not an experienced user to write my own script for my init file. Can you give an sample code to put my init file? Let say I want to bind Super + P key to a function that toggles current window to be not selectable?

Comment: Sample code didnt work for me. Probably I am doing something wrong. Did you try the code? 
Here what I do: I added sample code to my init file. I run M-x gdb and enable show many windows. Then I select *stack* window and do M-p. But still Its selectable with C-x o.

Comment: @aspirin Yes, it did. I had to bind it to `M-n` though, because `comint-mode` overwrites that key. The convention is that users should bind their things to something like `C-c LETTER`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to customize `other-window` you could try using [WindMove](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) which enables frame navigation by direction.